# Send email and update database

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I read items from the database using RepositoryItemReader
I then convert them to MimeMessages using a ItemProcessor
And I then send them using a MimeMessageItemWriter

All of this works great.

But when the Project email has been sent, I would like to update the database for that Project and set a sentMail date, so that next time the job is run, it doesn't resend the emails that have already gone out.

Where should I do the database change?

In the reader? but what happens if the smtp doesn't repond, is the whole chunk rolled back?
In the processor, or a composite processor?
In the writer? but that's no good because now it's a MimeMessage and I don't have the projectID any more.

Or should I use a listener?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a *service level* class that wraps the whole processing :

- read from database (and keep the id)
- create the MimeMessage
- send the message
- update database

That way you can update database only if you could successfully send the message (ok just to the SMTP server, but starting from that point it is another story ...)

Edit: in the context of spring-batch, the service level is spring-batch itself

In the context of spring-batch, the reader part is fine, and you should certainly use a `MimeMessageItemWriter` to send the message. But you must be able to follow the steps described above. IMHO a simple solution would be to extend the `MimeMessage` in a class :

```
class MessageAndId extends MimeMessage {
    private int databaseId; // or whatever your id is
    private boolean sendError;
    public MessageAndId(MimeMessage source, int databaseId) {
        super(source);
        this.databaseId = databaseId;
        sendError = false;
    }
}
```

Your ItemProcessor should convert your input to a `MessageAndId`, and your writer should be a composite writer, first calling a `MimeMessageItemWriter` with a custom error handler that would set `sendError`to true in its `handle` method, next calling the ItemWriter that would update the database knowing the database id and status of each message.

Comment: I'm new to spring batch. So how would I call my service level class from spring batch to get all the goodness of fault tolerans?